# Only delimit values with quotes and not the headers

Tags: python, csv, double-quotes

I am using python CSV module to write CSV file. I have used the following code to create the object for writing a CSV file

```
writer = csv.writer(stringIO, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

headers = ['HEADING1','HEADING2']
writer.writerow(headers)
values=['value1','value2']
writer.writerow(values)
```

But I only want to put double quotes around the values and not the headers.

For example I want the output as follows:

```
HEADING1,HEADING2
"value1","value2"
```

But I get the following

```
"HEADING1","HEADING2"
"value1","value2"
```

Please can someone suggest how I can get csv file with quotes only around the values and not the headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the headers separately, by creating a *new* `csv.writer()` for the rows:

```
writer = csv.writer(stringIO)
headers = ['HEADING1', 'HEADING2']
writer.writerow(headers)

writer = csv.writer(stringIO, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
values=['value1', 'value2']
writer.writerow(values)
```

`csv.writer()` objects have no way of switching between dialects. Just create a new object if you *have* to use a different dialect for some rows.